# Prove that the product $\prod_{k= 2}^n(1-k^{-3})$ is always greater than $1/2$.

Tags: real-analysis, euler-product

> Prove that $$\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^{3}}\right)\geq \frac{1}{2},\,\forall n\geq2.$$

Intuitively it looks very true and this looks very similar to the reciprocal of the Euler product. I checked in Mathematica and it seems to converge to 0.809... At n=10,000,000 Mathematica returned 0.809... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your claim that the product is always greater than 0.5 is correct but I think you made some error in your verification. W|A [shows](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cprod_%7Bk%3D2%7D%5En%5Cfrac%7Bk%5E3-1%7D%7Bk%5E3%7D) that the limit as $n\to\infty$ is $\dfrac{\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}2 \pi\right)}{3\pi}\approx 0.809$, so the product should never be less than that. Since all the terms in the product is less than $1$, the sequence of partial products is decreasing and every term is greater than the limiting value.

Comment: @learner - Correct re: limit, that is what I saw for $n$ at 1,000,000.

Comment: Could you provide your W|A-command to make your result reproducable? (It looks very unlikely to me)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean 0.5. It was a typo. I fixed it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is sufficient to prove the claim as $n\rightarrow \infty.$ We have $$\prod_{k\geq2}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^{3}}\right)\geq\prod_{k\geq2}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^{2}}\right)
 $$ now since from the Weierstrass product of the sine function $$\frac{\sin\left(\pi z\right)}{\pi z}=\prod_{k\geq1}\left(1-\frac{z^{2}}{k^{2}}\right)\Rightarrow\frac{\sin\left(\pi z\right)}{\pi z\left(1-z^{2}\right)}=\prod_{k\geq2}\left(1-\frac{z^{2}}{k^{2}}\right)\tag{1}
 $$ we have $$\prod_{k\geq2}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^{3}}\right)\geq\lim_{z\rightarrow1}\frac{\sin\left(\pi z\right)}{\pi z\left(1-z^{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}
 $$ as wanted. We can also prove the closed form of this product. Note that, from the Weierstass product of the hyperbolic cosine, that $$
\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}\right)=\prod_{k\geq1}\left(1+\frac{3}{\left(2k-1\right)^{2}}\right)=\prod_{k\geq2}\frac{4k^{2}-12k+12}{\left(2k-3\right)^{2}}
 $$ so we have $$\begin{align}\prod_{k\geq2}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^{3}}\right)=
  & \prod_{k\geq2}\frac{\left(k-1\right)\left(k^{2}+k+1\right)}{k^{3}}
 \\ =
  & \prod_{k\geq2}\frac{k-1}{k}\prod_{k\geq2}\frac{4k^{2}+4k+4}{4k^{2}}
  \\ =
  & \prod_{k\geq2}\frac{k-1}{k}\prod_{k\geq2}\frac{\left(2k-3\right)^{2}\left(2k+3\right)}{4k^{2}\left(2k+3\right)}\prod_{k\geq2}\frac{4k^{2}+4k+4}{\left(2k-3\right)^{2}}
  \\ =
  & \prod_{k\geq2}\frac{k-1}{k}\prod_{k\geq2}\frac{2k-3}{2k+3}\prod_{k\geq2}\frac{4k^{2}-9}{4k^{2}}\prod_{k\geq2}\frac{k^{2}+k+1}{k^{2}-3k+3}\prod_{k\geq2}\frac{4k^{2}-12k+12}{\left(2k-3\right)^{2}}.
  \end{align} $$ Now it is not difficult to see (we have telescoping products) that $$\prod_{k=2}^{N}\frac{k-1}{k}=\frac{1}{N}
 $$ $$\prod_{k=2}^{N}\frac{2k-3}{2k+3}=\frac{15}{8N^{3}+12N^{2}-2N-3}
 $$ and $$\prod_{k=2}^{N}\frac{k^{2}+k+1}{k^{2}-3k+3}=\prod_{k=2}^{N}\frac{(k+1)^{2}-k}{(k-1)^{2}-k+2}=\frac{N^{4}+N^{2}+1}{3}
 $$ hence $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{k=2}^{N}\frac{k-1}{k}\prod_{k=2}^{N}\frac{2k-3}{2k+3}\prod_{k=2}^{N}\frac{k^{2}+k+1}{k^{2}-3k+3}=\frac{15}{24}.
 $$ Using again $(1)$ we have $$\prod_{k\geq2}\frac{4k^{2}-9}{4k^{2}}=\prod_{k\geq2}\left(1-\frac{9}{4k^{2}}\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)}{\frac{3\pi}{2}\left(1-\frac{9}{4}\right)}=\frac{8}{15\pi}
 $$ so finally $$\prod_{k\geq2}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^{3}}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{3\pi}\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}\right)}\approx0.809
 $$ as wanted.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very good solution.

Comment: @mtheorylord You're welcome.

Answer (score 6):

For every $k \ge 2$, $k^3 - 1 > k^3 - k$. Substitute factor by factor in your product; it becomes a telescoping product, where all factors except the first and last cancel out.

The resulting product has the limit 1/2 - which means the original product has a limit strictly greater than 1/2. A quick computation in the Oracle database shows values above 0.8 for $n$ up to 1,000,000 - not sure what you entered in Mathematica but that seems wrong.  EDIT: This last comment is addressed to the OP, who originally claimed he found a limit or 1/2 in Mathematica (he has since changed his original post).

Comment: sorry, a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\prod_{k=2}^{n}\pars{1 - {1 \over k^{3}}} \geq \half\,,\quad
> \forall\ n \geq 2:\ ?}$

---

The roots of $\ds{z^{2} + z + 1 = 0}$ are given by $\ds{r}$ and $\ds{\ol{r}}$
where $\ds{r \equiv -\,\half + {\root{3} \over 2}\,\ic}$ and
$\ds{r \equiv -\,\half - {\root{3} \over 2}\,\ic}$. Nothe that
$\ds{r + \ol{r} = -1}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\prod_{k=2}^{n}\pars{1 - {1 \over k^{3}}}} & =
\prod_{k=2}^{n}{k^{3} - 1  \over k^{3}} =
\prod_{k=2}^{n}{\pars{k - 1}\pars{k - r}\pars{k - \ol{r}}  \over k^{3}}
\\[5mm] & =\
\overbrace{\pars{\prod_{k = 2}^{n}{1 \over k}}^{2}}
^{\ds{1 \over \pars{n!}^{2}}}\,\,\,
\overbrace{\pars{\prod_{k = 2}^{n}{k - 1 \over k}}}^{\ds{1 \over n}}\,\,\,
{\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\,\,\pars{k - r} \over -r\pars{1 - r}}\,\,\,
{\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\,\,\pars{k - \ol{r}} \over -\ol{r}\pars{1 - \ol{r}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over n\pars{n!}^{\, 2}}\,
\verts{{\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\,\,\pars{k - r} \over -r\pars{1 - r}}}^{2} =
{1 \over n\pars{n!}^{\, 2}}\,
{\verts{\vphantom{\Large A}\pars{-r}_{n + 1}}^{2} \over 3}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$\ds{\pars{a}_{m}\,\,\,}$ is a *Pochhammer Symbol*.

---

We'll use the following properties:
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcll}
\ds{\pars{a}_{m}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{\Gamma\pars{a + m} \over \Gamma\pars{a}}\,,\quad} &
\ds{\Gamma}\mbox{: Gamma Function}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\verts{\Gamma\pars{\half + y\ic}}^{2}} & \ds{=} & 
\ds{{\pi \over \cosh\pars{\pi y}}\,,\quad} & \ds{y \in \mathbb{R}}
\\ &&&
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

---

\begin{align}
\verts{\pars{-r}_{n + 1}}^{2} & =
\verts{\Gamma\pars{-r + n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{-r}}^{\, 2} =
{\verts{\vphantom{\large A}\pars{n - r}!}^{\, 2} \over
\verts{\vphantom{\Large A}\Gamma\pars{1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}}^{\, 2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \pi}\,\cosh\pars{{\root{3} \over 2}\,\pi}
\verts{\vphantom{\large A}\pars{n - r}!}^{\, 2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

With $\ds{\pars{1}\ \mbox{and}\ \pars{2}}$:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\prod_{k=2}^{\infty}\pars{1 - {1 \over k^{3}}}} & =
{1 \over 3\pi}\,\cosh\pars{{\root{3} \over 2}\,\pi}\,\ \overbrace{%
\lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,\verts{\pars{n - r}! \over n^{1/2}\,\, n!}^{\, 2}}
^{\ds{=\ \color{#f00}{1}}}\qquad
\pars{~\mbox{see}\ \ul{proof}\ \mbox{at the very end}~}
\\[5mm] & =
\color{#f00}{{1 \over 3\pi}\,\cosh\pars{{\root{3} \over 2}\,\pi}} \approx
0.8094
\end{align}

> \begin{align}\fbox{$\ds{\
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,\verts{\pars{n - r}! \over n^{1/2}\,\, n!}^{\, 2}\
> }$} & =
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,\verts{{1 \over n^{1/2}}\,
> {\root{2\pi}\pars{n - r}^{n - r + 1/2}\,\,\expo{-\pars{n - r}} \over
> \root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\,\,\expo{-n}}}^{\, 2}
> \\[5mm] & =
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,\verts{
> {n^{1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2} \over n^{1/2}}\,\,\pars{1 - {r \over n}}^{-r}
> \pars{1 - {r \over n}}^{n + 1/2}\,\,\expo{r}}^{\, 2}
> \\[5mm] & =
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,\bracks{n^{-\root{3}\ic/2}\,\,\,
> n^{\root{3}\ic/2}\,\, \times 1^{2} \times \expo{-r}\,\expo{r}
> \expo{-\ol{r}}\,\expo{\ol{r}}}
> = \fbox{$\ds{\ 1\ }$}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

This can be proved by induction if we strengthened the inequality.

We can't induct directly since $ \frac{1}{2} ( 1 - \frac{1}{(k+1)^3 })  <  \frac{1}{2}$.

However, the trick is to find a function $ g(k) $ such that

- $ g(k) ( 1 - \frac{1}{(k+1)^2 }) > g(k+1)$,
- $ g(2) < 1 - \frac{1}{2^3} $, and
- $ g(k) > \frac{1}{2}$.

With such a $g(k)$, it's clear that induction on $ \prod ( 1 - \frac{1}{k^3 }) > g(k) > \frac{1}{2}$ works.

There are several candidates for such a function.
If you can't one, you can reveal it below.

> $g(k) = \frac{1}{2} +  \frac{1}{ k+1} $.